# I can't get suggestions to import spring classes in Itellij

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I can't get suggestions to import spring classes in the list of import suggestions in IntelliJ IDE

[image: screan-1]

so i have to import them manually

[image: screan-2]

Is there any way to auto-import them ?

Comment: Did you include the corresponding JAR for spring-boot?

Comment: I did include all maven's dependencies needed, and the code works fine when i write the whole import line manually

Comment: Hey @mahmoudzridi did you enable auto-import for maven in intellij? Maven may have not downloaded the dependencies yet.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-importing.html

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem by removing spring package from  "Exclude from import and complition" from File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import.

I think it was a miss click

[image: screan3]